# stream api with curly brackets

Tags: java, api, lambda, java-stream

I have a question that finding an answer to should be easy, yet I can't find it. I'm new in Java, I use mostly C#.

Suppose we have the following code:

```
List<Double> mean = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(dim, .0));
//some stuff
mean = mean.stream().map(num->num/=dim).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It'a all cool. Now let's say I want to do many operations, not only one divide inside lamba function. Then I thought it must be with using curly brackets, I've ever seen some of examples, yet when I change it to:

```
List<Double> mean = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(dim, .0));
//some stuff
mean = mean.stream().map(num-> {num/=dim; /* other stuff */}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It gives me an error that this method is not capable for arguments `(([no_type]num)->{})`. I've tried using explicit cast, but it stays the same. I'm sure I could do something like this in C#.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: The method map(Function<? super Double,? extends R>) in the type Stream<Double> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> num) -> {}).

Comment: See Louis' answer. If you use  { } and return a value, you must say `return expression;`

Comment: thanks for that /* other stuff */ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do multiple operations inside a lambda, you will have to write it as

```
num-> {
  return num/=dim;
}
```

with a `return` statement to get the final output.  If you write lambdas like this with braces, it is exactly like implementing a function: you need a `return` statement, but you may have as much code as you like inside the lambda.

Comment: Oh, that's right, that must have been something easy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that using `/=` is completely unnecessary and confusing here. Just use `num / dim`.

Comment: Note that when you have lambda like `num->num/dim` in a valid context, every IDE should offer an option to do the conversion to `num->{ return num/dim; }` for you. E.g. in Netbeans the option is labelled “*Use block as lambda's body*”.